# simple reading of fortran binary data not so simple in python

Tags: python, fortran, binaryfiles, unpack

I have a binary output file from a FORTRAN code.  Want to read it in python.  (Reading with FORTRAN and outputting text to read for python is not an option.  Long story.)  I can read the first record in a simplistic manner:

```
>>> binfile=open('myfile','rb')
>>> pad1=struct.unpack('i',binfile.read(4))[0]
>>> ver=struct.unpack('d',binfile.read(8))[0]
>>> pad2=struct.unpack('i',binfile.read(4))[0]
>>> pad1,ver,pad2
(8,3.13,8)
```

Just fine.  But this is a big file and I need to do this more efficiently.  So I try:

```
>>> (pad1,ver,pad2)=struct.unpack('idi',binfile.read(16))
```

This won't run.  Gives me an error and tells me that unpack needs an argument with a length of 20.  This makes no sense to me since the last time I checked, 4+8+4=16.  When I give in and replace the 16 with 20, it runs, but the three numbers are populated with numerical junk.  Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size you get is due to alignment, try `struct.calcsize('idi')` to verify the size is actually 20 after alignment. To use the native byte-order without alignment, specify `struct.calcsize('=idi')` and adapt it to your example.

For more info on the `struct` module, check http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Answer (score 6):

The `struct` module is mainly intended to interoperate with C structures and because of this it aligns the data members. `idi` corresponds to the following C structure:

```
struct
{
   int int1;
   double double1;
   int int2;
}
```

`double` entries require 8 byte alignment in order to function efficiently (or even correctly) with most CPU load operations. That's why 4 bytes of padding are being added between `int1` and `double1`, which increases the size of the structure to 20 bytes. The same padding is performed by the `struct` module, unless you suppress the padding by adding `<` (on little endian machines) or `>` (on big endian machines), or simply `=` at the beginning of the format string:

```
>>> struct.unpack('idi', d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 20
>>> struct.unpack('<idi', d)
(-1345385859, 2038.0682530887993, 428226400)
>>> struct.unpack('=idi', d)
(-1345385859, 2038.0682530887993, 428226400)
```

(`d` is a string of 16 random chars.)

Comment: OK, makes more sense now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using arrays to read a file that was written by FORTRAN with UNFORMATTED, SEQUENTIAL.

Your specific example using arrays, would be as follows:

```
import array
binfile=open('myfile','rb')
pad = array.array('i')
ver = array.array('d')
pad.fromfile(binfile,1)   # read the length of the record 
ver.fromfile(binfile,1)   # read the actual data written by FORTRAN
pad.fromfile(binfile,1)   # read the length of the record
```

If you have FORTRAN records that write arrays of integers and doubles, which is very common, your python would look something like this:

```
import array
binfile=open('myfile','rb')
pad = array.array('i')
my_integers = array.array('i')
my_floats = array.array('d')
number_of_integers = 1000 # replace with how many you need to read
number_of_floats = 10000 # replace with how many you need to read
pad.fromfile(binfile,1)   # read the length of the record
my_integers.fromfile(binfile,number_of_integers) # read the integer data
my_floats.fromfile(binfile,number_of_floats)     # read the double data
pad.fromfile(binfile,1)   # read the length of the record
```

Final comment is that if you have characters on the file, you can read those into an array as well, and then decode it into a string. Something like this:

```
import array
binfile=open('myfile','rb')
pad = array.array('i')
my_characters = array.array('B')
number_of_characters = 63 # replace with number of characters to read
pad.fromfile(binfile,1)   # read the length of the record 
my_characters.fromfile(binfile,number_of_characters ) # read the data
my_string = my_characters.tobytes().decode(encoding='utf_8') 
pad.fromfile(binfile,1)   # read the length of the record
```

Comment: @Tunaki Interesting.  I wasn't aware of the "array" module.  Will have to look into it. Thanks!